# What is the fastest way to run predictions on a big dataset using pandas, numpy and keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, pandas, predictive-modeling, numpy

I am a bit new to the field of data science and could really use some help.
I used a **natural language** dictionary to train and test an ml model using keras and tensorflow.
It detects the sentiments in a string and returns 0 or 1.
Now, I have a dataset containing about **200,000** rows with each row containing 1 or 2 paragraphs of text and I wrote a quick function that checks and returns the sentimental polarity of each row and I am currently using a single for loop to parse through the dataset, check the string from each row and append the polarity into an empty column. It works perfectly when I tried it on a smaller subset of 100 rows.

The above process is **extremely slow** and on my current setup and 200,000 rows will take maybe more than a week to process. I am using sagemaker notebooks with a c5.xlarge instance currently and cant afford to get better compute hardware.
Do you guys have any advice on how to deal with this? Any help will be much appreciated!

````
def predictions(texter):
  texter = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texter)
  texter = pad_sequences(texter, maxlen = 96, dtype = 'int32', value = 0)
  sentiment = model.predict(texter ,batch_size = 1, verbose = 0)[0]
  sentiment = [float(a)/sum(sentiment) for a in sentiment]
  if ((sentiment[0]*100)>75):
    return '0'
  else:
    return '1'

for i in range (len(df['body'])):
  df['bodysentiment'][i] = predictions(df['body'][i])
```
````

Comment: Have you tried using `.apply()` instead of manually looping over the rows? Manually looping in `pandas` is the slowest way of applying a function to every row. In addition, can the `texts_to_sequences` and `pad_sequences` functions be applied to all rows at once?

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestions.
I tried apply using this 

df['bodysentiment'] = df.apply(lambda row: predictions(df['body']), axis=1)

but it didnt make much difference 
on the 100 rows set, a for loop timed at 45 seconds, and .apply took 42 seconds. Although it helps, i want the process to be way more quicker.

Comment: As Nicolas points out, start by looking which of lines in your function are taking the most time to see where to focus your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions:

- Detect the lines of code that last longer than the other with the Python's time function.
- Generally speaking, PC processors have 4 cores and you can benefit from each of them if you apply multiprocessing with pandas thanks to the multiprocessing library.
- Pypy is a very good library to run code very fast, even faster than Cython (https://www.pypy.org/)
- .iterrows() or .loc could perform better (for loops are too slow).
- Google collab uses plenty of powerful servers that could process lot of data in minutes instead of days in many cases.